# Error using Regex with Unison

Tags: regular-expression, unison

Using unison for synchronization on mac, I would like to ignore files such as `.DS_store` in each directory. In my profile file, I put, as described in section "Ignored path" of [the page](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore).

```
ignore = Regex *.DS_Store
ignore = Regex *\.DS_Store
ignore = Regex "*.DS_Store"
```

but either it didn't work or I have the error:  `line 33: Malformed pattern "Regex *.DS_Store"`.

Comment: Because you used wildcard syntax, but `Regex` requires a regex.

Comment: To clarify: you are using the * like a wildcard glob instead of as the regular expression Kleene star which must have a preceding character. This should work: .*\.DS_Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for this; the standard globbing patterns that Unison uses for all pattern matching without the `Regex` command will do just fine.

```
ignore = Name *.DS_Store
```